# What is the use of curly braces in Dart method signature

Tags: syntax, constructor, dart

```
class TapboxA extends StatefulWidget {

 TapboxA({Key key}) : super(key: key);

}
```

This part :

```
TapboxA({Key key})
```

The second half

```
super(key: key);
```

I understand, (a call to super class constructor).

But what is the

```
{Key key}
```

syntax doing?

Answer (score 7):

In Dart constructors ( and other methods ) can have optional named parameters :

```
MyClass({String namedParam}){//...}
```

In the case of a Flutter widget constructor :

```
TapboxA({Key key})  // TapboxA constructor defines a named parameters `key`
: super(key: key); //which is used within the super constructor call (which also has `key` as named parameter )
```

You can find more information about  [optional named parameters in the Dart language tour](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#optional-named-parameters)

Comment: Where is the value of "key" obtained from? 

I see this code in widget  "child: new TapboxA()," 

with no value for the named parameter supplied....

Comment: @SirPaulMuaddib It's because optional parameters are **optional** :)

Comment: @SirPaulMuaddib Keys are used for a fined-grained control over Widgets rebuilds. In a infinite scroll list you are able to avoid full rebuild of the entire list by assigning to its items a key, as new items are added to list, the previous ones aren't rebuilt unless its Key, along with its runtimType matches: https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/#keys

Answer (score 3):

Dart provides an option on constructors. By default, when you instantiate a class with a constructor you are forced to provide the parameters defined.

Therefore, `TapboxA({Key key})` means you can instantiate the class *without* providing the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

It's not something special with constructors only.

For all Dart methods we have the option of named arguments as in languages like Python

Using a curly brace syntax, you can define optional parameters that have names.

So with the method signature using the curly braces,

```
TapboxA({Key key}) :
```

you can call this constructor in two different ways

The usual method, without named parameter

```
tapboxA1 = TapboxA(keyObject)
```

The extra nicety of named parameter

```
tapboxA2 = TapboxA(key: keyObject)
```

In other words the usefulness comes at the time of calling the method, not in the method itself.